# Truncate tables in databases T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am planning to write a stored procedure in T-SQL to truncate the tables in a specific database and schema.

The idea is to store all the table names in a table. The table has got 4 columns, those are database name, schema name, table name and flag.

If the flag value is set 0, then the stored procedure should truncate all those tables.

Can anybody give some insight on this?

Comment: If that is what you need to do, then do it.  You'll need to use dynamic SQL, possibly with cursors.  What is your real question?

Comment: yes I am doing it. Thought to get some more  insight from experts

Comment: So do it and if you have a specific question about some part come back and ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a table called @tables where you store the details of the tables to be truncated, You can use the following logic/cursor inside your stored procedure to Truncate these tables.

**Table Holding Tables Info**

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE (DBName SYSNAME ,  SchemaName SYSNAME 
                    ,TableName SYSNAME, Flag INT);
INSERT INTO @Tables VALUES 
('TestDB' , 'dbo', 'TestTable1', 0),
('TestDB' , 'dbo', 'TestTable2', 0),
('TestDB' , 'dbo', 'TestTable3', 1)
```

**Stored Procedure Code**

```
Declare @DB     SYSNAME 
      , @Schema SYSNAME
      , @Table  SYSNAME 
      , @Sql    VARCHAR(MAX);


Declare Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT DBName , SchemaName , TableName
FROM @Tables  
WHERE Flag = 0 

OPEN Cur 
  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DB , @Schema , @Table

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

 SET @Sql = N'TRUNCATE TABLE '
            + QUOTENAME (@DB) + '.' + QUOTENAME (@Schema) + '.' +  QUOTENAME (@Table) 

    Exec sp_executesql  @Sql

  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @DB , @Schema , @Table

END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
Declare @Table table (dbname varchar(50),schem varchar(50),tablename varchar(50),flag bit)
Insert into @Table (dbname,schem,tablename,flag) values
('dbName1','dbo','MyTable1',0),
('dbName2','dbo','MyTableA',1),
('dbName1','dbo','MyTableB',0),
('dbName2','dbo','MyTableZ',1),
('dbName1','dbo','MyTable2',0)


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = coalesce(@SQL,' ') + ';truncate table [' +dbname +'].[' + schem +'].[' + tablename +']'
 From @Table
 Where Flag=1

Select @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```